# frequency for common amplitude between sin and cos functions

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Given:

$J_c = \sigma \sin(\omega t)$

$J_d =  \omega~ \varepsilon \cos(\omega t)$

What is the frequency $\omega$ at which $J_c = J_d$?

Here's my work:

$\sigma \sin(\omega t) = \omega~ \varepsilon \cos(\omega t)$

$\sigma = \omega~\epsilon$

$\boxed{\omega = \frac{\sigma}{\varepsilon}}$

Is this formula for $\omega$ valid?

It seems to me that the phase wouldn't match if we equate only the the amplitudes of the two sinusoids, since the left-hand-side (Sin) is out of phase with the right-hand-side (cos)?

However, the physics book i'm looking at says its valid...  I just wanted to understand why this is true.

Comment: the more i think about it... I think its really a system of 2 equations and 2 unknowns: t time, and $\omega $ frequency where $J_c$ and $J_d$ are equal...

Comment: $\sin 45^{\circ} = \cos 45^{\circ}$

Comment: my conclusion is that its valid because there's one point in time during the frequency cycle where sin = cos..  thus, its ok to equate the amplitude of the sinusoids and solved them for omega.

Comment: I am not sure what physics book you are using, but why did you choose $\cot (\omega t)=1$?

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* You want to solve an equation of the form $$A\cos\omega t+B\sin \omega t=0.$$ You can always write $\text{LHS}$ as $R\sin(\omega t+\phi),$ where $R$ and $\phi$ depend on $A$ and $B.$ Then you simply want to solve something of the form $\sin y=0,$ whose solutions are $y=πk$ for any integer $k.$